# .htaccess which somehow prevents Google to put some PageRank on my domains

Tags: .htaccess, pagerank, rank

I am using the following .htaccess code on all my domains since 2+ years ago on some projects, but no one of the websites build has ever got any Google PageRank, at least '1' bar. On all websites on which I don't use this code, I am getting a reasonable PageRank.

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# rewrite the non 'www' addresses
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# rewrite REQUEST_URI
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

some of my websites using this .htaccess:

- http://www.kampril.bg/
- http://www.milleniumbg.eu/

Answer (score 0):

Register these domains in the Google Search Console and check whether Google returns some error messages or some feedback about these. Submit some sitemaps.

If you do not see any error messages or warnings, then it simply means Google does not find the content of your websites interesting.